# Which is the correct way of handling imports in complex Python project?

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have always used Python for single-file scripts and now I am working on my first "complex" project, so I have not experience with packages in Python (3.x).

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I am missing something for successfully organizing module imports in my project, which should be used as a library.

Assuming following project tree:

```
myProject/
- subpackage1/
   - __init__.py
   - other1.py
- subpackage2/
   - __init__.py
   - other2.py
- __init__.py
- foo.py
- bar.py
```

**Which is the correct way of importing modules from each other?** In particular:

1. importing `foo` from `bar`
2. importing `foo` from `other1`
3. importing `other1` from `other2`
4. importing `foo` (which is a library) from a different directory during development (are virtual environments the right choice?)

Thanks!

EDIT: (to make the question more specific) I obviously tried different approaches before asking. What I saw in some popular projects is using absolute imports like `from myProject.subpackage1.other1 import something`. It looks like a clean solution (similar to what I'm used to do in Java), but when adopting this approach I can't simply run my code due to import errors. Could `virtualenv` be a solution to install the packages before trying to import them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Importing `foo` from `bar`

As [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) says, you can import modules from the same directory by importing `from .`. For example:

```
from . import foo
```

If `bar` is executed with `python bar.py` then you could also import it absolutely, like any other module:

```
import foo
```

This works since the parent directory of the executed file is added to the module search path ([sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.path)/[PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH)). However, I wouldn't rely on that behaviour since it means different things for imported modules and the main module.

## 2. Importing `foo` from `other1`

If you're using the relative import syntax then you can add another `.` to mean the parent directory:

```
from .. import foo
```

## 3. Importing `other1` from `other2`

This shouldn't be much of a surprise by now, but you can use relative imports with modules in subpackages, too:

```
from ..subpackage1 import other1
```

## 4. Importing `foo` (a library) from a different directory during development

I'm assuming that by "a different directory" you mean "a different project". In that case, yes, you'd want to package `foo` as a distutils/setuptools package, and then install that into a virtualenv for the other project.

Exactly how to do that is a bit more involved for a post that's already getting pretty long, but the setuptools website has a pretty decent [tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide) for doing this.